# How to mount ISO loaded over IPMI client's "virtual storage"

Tags: centos7, ipmi

My kernel got corrupted during an update because my boot partition ran out of space.   I made the mistake of rebooting before making sure everything was reinstalled and ok.

So now the system will only boot in rescue mode, and the only access I have to it is via a flaky IPMI java client.

I put the kernel RPM inside an ISO, and I managed to attach the ISO to the IPMI client's "virtual storage" facility, but I have no idea how to access the ISO inside the rescue mode linux instance.

Is mounting the ISO possible?  If not, is there any other way to get a file to the server?   I only have IPMI access.

I notice in /var/log/messages when I "connect" the ISO, I see a message about a new USB device, device #11, but I don't see what file in /dev/ that corresponds to.

[image]

Comment: Can you not boot an earlier kernel version from the boot menu ?

Comment: @Iain nope, whoever made this server insufficiently sized /boot, so only 1 kernel fits.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work:

1. mount a live cd ISO from the IPMI client,
2. reset power, press F11 to bring up the one-time boot screen,
3. boot into the live cd (yes, even the gui worked over IPMI),
4. mount the original file system and
5. download the kernel files I needed.
6. reboot to the rescue kernel
7. yum reinstall /path/to/kernel.rpm